# Create dynamic <select> with PHP

Tags: php

I have a `$_SESSION` variable `$_SESSION['invoiceDate']` that is populated with a value representing `YYYYMM`.

I need to dynamically build a select element so that I have 6 options going back from the 'invoiceDate' e.g. if `$_SESSION['invoiceDate'] = 201602` the output should be...

```
<select id="invoiceDate" name="invoiceDate">
    <option value="201602">Feb 2016</option>
    <option value="201601">Jan 2016</option>
    <option value="201512">Dec 2015</option>
    <option value="201511">Nov 2015</option>
    <option value="201510">Oct 2015</option>
    <option value="201509">Sep 2015</option>
</select>
```

My PHP is very basic... I can split the session value and assign the first 4 digits to $year and the other 2 to $month. Then loop 6 times... Each time I echo to output the `<option>` line concatenating the year and month to make the value and then subtracting 1 from the month and if month=0 then take 1 from year and make month 12. This gives me....

```
    <option value="201602"></option>
    <option value="201601"></option>
    <option value="201512"></option>
    <option value="201511"></option>
    <option value="201510"></option>
    <option value="201509"></option>
```

Now I can join the year and month with a hyphen to give

```
    <option value="201602">2016-02</option>
    <option value="201601">2016-01</option>
    <option value="201512">2015-12</option>
    <option value="201511">2015-11</option>
    <option value="201510">2015-10</option>
    <option value="201509">2015-09</option>
```

But how do I get a Month Year instead... e.g. Feb 2016 instead of 2016-02?

Comment: Its very easy, wait for my answer.

Comment: you have only `201602` but how `201601`, `201512` come?

Comment: as I described... I have a php code that takes 201602 and splits into 2016 and asign to $year and 02 assign to $month then loops 6 time and output echo '<option value="'.$year.$month.'">'.$year.'-'.$month.'</option>'; then it subtracts 1 from $month and if $month=0 then subtract 1 from $year and make $month = 12...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)?

```
$e = '201602';
$date = new DateTime($e);
echo $date->format('M');
```

outputs `Feb`

In your case it could be

```
$e = '201602';
$date = new DateTime($e);
$month = $date->format('n');

for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
{
   echo '<option value="'.$date->format('Ym').'">'.$date->format('M Y').'</option>';
   $date = $date->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
}
```

This outputs

```
<option value="201602">Feb 2016</option>
<option value="201601">Jan 2016</option>
<option value="201512">Dec 2015</option>
<option value="201511">Nov 2015</option>
<option value="201510">Oct 2015</option>
<option value="201509">Sep 2015</option>
```

Just edit this as you need and don't use that infernal version of `date` with `strtotime`...

Comment: A very nice solution but it does not give me the value parameter I need as this is used in POST... I need <option value="201602">Feb 2016</option>

Comment: @Mych Sorry, I faultly assumed you'd be able to derive it from my post... I updated my answer

Comment: Had an bug but fixed by changing $e = $_Session['invoiceDate']; to $e_SESSION['invoicecDate']."01"; to make it a full date string. Also had to specify date_default_timezone_set().

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = "201602";
for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
    echo date('M, Y',strtotime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date))." -$i month"));
}
```

In this loop we are deleting 1 month from your date.
[Date Parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: You did it before me. I am late cause i go for whole design.

Comment: `date(...strtotime(...date(...strtotime` is really bad design

Answer (score 0):

**This is it:**

```
<?php $session_val = "201602";?>
<select id="invoiceDate" name="invoiceDate">
<?php
  for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){
    //$text = date('Y-m', strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($session_val))." -$i month")); // for 2016-02
    $text = date('M Y', strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($session_val))." -$i month")); //for Feb 2016
    $val = date('Ym', strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($session_val))." -$i month"));
    echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$text.'</option>';
}?>
</select>
```

> I did this in my local, but when i am going to post i see some one
>   post similar thing. But I did so i post.

Comment: `date(...strtotime(...date(...strtotime` is really bad design

Comment: Thanks Frayne... your solution also worked but the above solution was just easier to use.

Comment: If it is worked then you can upvote, but accept that answer which one is best.