# populate array to dropdown list in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to populate a dropdown list with the values of an array that I am getting it from one cell in the database,

for example:

I have one column called options and I am storing the data in this column as an array[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDQ4o.png)
you can see options columns,

I tried to

```
<?php
$data = $feedbacks_list[$i]['options'];
$data_array[] = explode('|', $data);
print_r($data_array[$i]);
?>
```

in options tag

can anyone help me to populate this to dropdown list? 
its showing the array in the dropdown list instead of items

Comment: you need to iterate over array items and build the option tag dynamically see this link: https://www.tutdepot.com/dynamic-select-menu-with-php/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create dynamic <select> with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624645/create-dynamic-select-with-php)